# Getting events of another application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

In my c# application I need to detect when a user clicks one of two buttons in a different, third party application.

I am able to get the Handle of the application but the `MainWindowHandle` returns 0.

I tried `WndProc` but for some reason the event will not fire in my application.

How can I get/intercept the button click event from that application into mine?

Comment: Is that third party app exposes events which you can hook up? Is that button used in that third party is made public access to you? Or even atleast protected?

Comment: Can you make a few modifications on the third party ?

Comment: @user390480: in what language and framework is the 3rd party application written in?

Comment: I do not believe the buttons have public access.  I cannot modify the app.  I think it's written in either c++ or maybe .NET 2003 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global system hooks allow an application to intercept Windows messages intended for other applications. This has always been difficult to implement in C#. This project on Codeplex attempts to implement global system hooks by creating a DLL wrapper in C++ that posts messages to the hooking application's message queue. Put simply, this lets you implement any type of global Windows hook from managed code: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx