# Handle events from another application

Tags: c#, process, event-handling

Hellu

The question is simple, yet the answers seem to be various and pretty unclear.

**How can I, in an application A, handle events sent by an application B, and how to implements those events in B?** Knowing that B has no idea of the existence of A.

Let's say B is a "batch-like" type of program, doing things in the back with no graphical display whatsoever, and A is the nice GUI *(pun intended)* that should write messages B sends him in a dialog or something.

I found interesting answers about this (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977/3283203) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904544/getting-events-of-another-application)), but none actually answers the issue with example for C#; at best, they redirect to some external tools.

I heard it was an issue in C#, but in the end, is there a clean way to do it? Thanks.

If that can ease the thing, let's say A launches B (with Process or something), knowing that B can also be launched alone (in which case, I don't need this whole event handling thing).

Comment: are you talking about hooking into another app?? 
or is it limited to just getting messages from one app into the second?

Comment: A just needs to receive B's messages, nothing more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a combination of `MemoryMappedFile`, `Mutex` and `EventWaitHandle` to manage this between processes.

The following example shows how it would work. In real code, the `producer()` method would be in a different application from the `consumer()` method, but this serves to illustrate an implementation:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            Task.Run(() => consumer());
            Task.Run(() => producer());

            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to stop.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void producer()
        {
            using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("MyMapName", 1024))
            using (var view = mmf.CreateViewStream())
            {
                var writer = new BinaryWriter(view);
                var signal = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "MyEventName");
                var mutex = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
                {
                    string message = "Message #" + i;

                    mutex.WaitOne();
                    writer.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    writer.Write(message);
                    signal.Set();
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }

        static void consumer()
        {
            using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("MyMapName", 1024))
            using (var view = mmf.CreateViewStream())
            {
                var reader = new BinaryReader(view);
                var signal = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "MyEventName");
                var mutex = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");

                while (true)
                {
                    signal.WaitOne();
                    mutex.WaitOne();
                    reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    var message = reader.ReadString();
                    Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + message);
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: This implementation does not use a queue, so it is possible for the consumer to miss messages if it does not process them before a new message arrives.

If you must not miss any messages, you would have to use some kind of queuing implementation instead, for example [MSMQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5830/Using-MSMQ-from-C).

However, you could also consider using [Windows Communications Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx), which allows you to call remote methods in another process - but that might require more coupling between processes than you want.

Finally, another possibility is to use a [`Named Pipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I actually think this might be the best solution for you.

There's a Microsoft example showing server and client IPC using a named pipe here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: At first glance, I like that, it's clever. I'm going to try it.

Comment: It is somewhat simplistic and suffers from the major drawback that you could miss events, but it might be the *simplest* solution for you if that isn't a problem.

Comment: My only objective is to notify a user of the state of my background action, if he launched it with the GUI app. Missing a message is, I guess, no big deal, since if the consumer didn't have enough time to display it, the user would probably not have the time to read it :p

Comment: I have a question: so if I launch my producer process without the consumer one, won't it produces unexpected issues about signal not getting received or something?

Comment: @Kilazur No, the messages will just be ignored (you can test this by commenting out the `Task.Run(() => consumer());` in my sample program.)

Comment: Perfect then, gonna be accepted as soon as I tested it in my program. Though I don't have any `Task.Run` method, settling with `new Task(Action).Start();`

Comment: exactly what I was looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432877/shard-memory-ipc-triggers-the-eventhandler-on-console-fails-on-wpf-application

Answer (score 0):

depends on how complex your scenario would get. 
You could use Interprocess communication or even some simple file (or db table) which would be written/read by the 2 apps (you'll need to sync access to it).

Comment: Oh, the scenario couldn't be simpler. In the ideal scenario, B has a property `public string Message` that fires a OnMessageChanged event when set'd.

Comment: ok, but how do you plan to subscribe to an event triggered by app B in app A? as far as I know, you can't.

Comment: I did, his example looks great and I'm probably gonna use it. Though it doesn't work as I wanted it to, I guess there's no way to do it this way.