# How to attach a click event to an .exe file controls?

Tags: c#, events, process

I have an .exe windows desktop application (WinForm), but I don't have access to the code of that .exe file. I want to handle a double click event to that .exe controls which are rendered already inside the application.

As I don't have the code of that so I started the following approach to do this.

1. I have a C# program which runs in the background and captures all double click events (using Hook concepts).
2. When any double click event is generated on the desktop, then I check whether my .exe is running or not.

   Process.GetProcesByName("My exe name");

So if my .exe is running then I do my business logic.

**Problem** :- I dont want to call business logic when my .exe is just running but not in foreground. It should be on foreground then only I have to call my business logic.

So here I want that check which tells me whether my .exe is on foreground or not through my C# code.

If the approach itself is not correct then please suggest me the other ways to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting events of another application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904544/getting-events-of-another-application)

Comment: Not duplicate because up to global hooking its working fine. The problem comes while checking whether my .exe is on foreground or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yeahh, finally this is the code which is working as expected.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

            if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
            {
                return Buff.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Then inside my global hook events,

```
private void HookManager_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        string activeWindow = this.GetActiveWindowTitle();

        if (activeWindow.ToLower().Contains("my .exe name") && e.X >= 64 && e.X <= 86 && e.Y >= 32 && e.Y <= 54)
            CallChildProcess();                       
    }
```

Please refer to the below link for global hooks events.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C?msg=5288013#xx5288013xx